# Whatsapp is not working

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-denim-update

Ever since I updated to Denim update, WhatsApp started to crash whenever I open it. I have tried rebooting my phone, reinstalling WhatsApp (uninstall>reboot>reinstall), resetting my phone, and clearing out my phone memory. Is anyone here facing the same problem? I will appreciate any solutions you offer.